# Google script Publish as a service

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm coding an actual production application for Field Trip approval for our school district. I went to Publish to select "Publish as a Service" and get the URL, but it isn't there anymore! Now I have only "Deploy as web app".

I want to include this URL in an email so the user can click it and approve the trip.

I first saw this in a video by Eric Koleda at the end of May 2012 for approval of Announcements. I got that test to work at that time.

Until I hear from someone, I'll try the "Deploy as web app" URL.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they've changed the terms used . See the [release notes from June 18](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes).

Also, you'll now have to save your script with a version before you can deploy it as a web app